# Transitioning to Version Control

Tags: software-development, version-control-systems

Until now, we have not had an application version strategy or version-ed our application. We are considering doing so with our next release. What are the minimum tasks necessary to transition to a version-ed application? Answers in the form of bullet points, not necessarily in chronological order would be sufficient. It's okay to keep it high level. A few examples might be:

- Determine version control name convention Major.Minor.Build.YY...
- Revise on screen imaging or text to display current version
- Prepare release notes template for communicating new releases to users
- We're a .Net shop using TFS if that helps.

If it's not obvious already, I'm not a developer. I'm the solution expert/BA acting often as the project manager.

Comment: http://semver.org/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't specifically related to open source, but goes for all kinds of software development. It's a good question though. It could maybe fit on stackoverflow or programmers.stackexchange

Comment: @Martijn I don't think a question *has* to be specific to open source to be on-topic and it arguably would just get sent back to us if migrated (it's broad, and it fits better here than anywhere else).

Comment: @Drano, seeing that your relatively new to Stack Exchange, we've placed your question on-hold mostly because there are many steps to the Version Control process. As the close reason applies, you can [edit](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/posts/2170/edit) to try to isolate a specific issue that you are facing, so that we can answer the underlying question with better quality. Thanks :D

Comment: You've more or less got it. If you've automated your builds, you could also leverage your build system to monkey patch the version numbers.

Comment: Check out the major contenders for distributed version control systems (centralized systems don't cut it, in my humble opinion, both in development flexibility and on technical grounds; "distributed" *can* be used centralized, but not the other way around). Look for git and mercurial, there are tons of documentation on each, and plenty of sites offering hosting.